# android thread only runs once

Tags: android, multithreading

I just wanted to test `Log.i()` and look at the console in android studio. In the code below `onResume` should start the `thread` and `run()` should write an endless stream of "dings" with the tag "run" in the monitor. But the run method apparently only gets called once. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
    Thread gameThread = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("onCreate","getting started");
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i("run","ding");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the notion of what threading really does. It allows you to run a unit of work asynchronously. So, all the same normal rules apply. The reason it only runs once, is because the thread exits after `run()` returns. So just like any other method, you should put something like

```
while(true)
{
    Log.i("run","ding");
}
```

inside of `run()`. Ideally you would actually check some condition so that you can exit the thread as needed.

Finally, it is probably a bad idea to have your `MainActivity` implement `Runnable`. Typically it is good style to have a thread implemented by its own class, for example `DingThread implements Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `while` loop that why its run only once. Use below code. This is the better approach to use thread concept.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("onCreate","getting started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startThread();// create thread obj and start
    }

    private GameThread mGameThread = null;
    private void startThread() {
        stopThread();// if thread already running stop it then create new thread  and start (for avoiding multi-threading).
        mGameThread = new GameThread();
        mGameThread.start();//start the thread.
    }

    //To stop the thread simply call this method.
    private void stopThread() {
        if(mGameThread != null) {
            mGameThread.setStop();
            mGameThread = null;
        }
    }

    private class GameThread extends Thread {
        private boolean mIsStop;// mIsStop is default false

        @Override
        public void run() {
           while (!mIsStop) {    // if mIsStop is false then only come inside loop.
               Log.i("run","ding");    //log will print
           }
        }

        public void setStop() {
            mIsStop = true;// set mIStop variable to true.
        }
    }
}
```